# Finding the vote count for a Debate on TTIP in the EU parliament

Tags: voting, european-union, treaty, trade, ttip

I've been trying to find the exact vote count for the debate that took place yesterday on TTIP at the European Parliament but can't find it. I only found one count of 436 for and 216 against or something like that. Which seems unlikely after what happened in June. (besides being depressing)

If that count is correct where can I find what MEP's voted for what? I checked the page of the European parliament and found an insanely cryptic document about the vote that I absolutely do not understand.

Could someone help a fellow EU resident understand how my parliament is voting?

[Relevant cryptic vote count](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sed/doc/votingList/(A8-0175_2015).pdf)

Comment: There's also something [here](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?type=REPORT&reference=A8-2015-0175&language=EN#title1) but it doesn't seem to contain the plenary voting list.

Comment: The adopted motion itself is [available here (PDF 246 kB)](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?pubRef=-//EP//NONSGML+TA+P8-TA-2015-0252+0+DOC+PDF+V0//EN) but doesn't contain the voting list either.

Comment: [This page](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/oeil/popups/ficheprocedure.do?lang=en&reference=2014/2228%28INI%29#keyEvents) seems to have voting results but right now (2015-07-09T09:05:30Z) lists this one as *vote scheduled*.  Perhaps it takes a few days for it to appear online?

Comment: @gerrit Yes maybe. I hope they publish the list. I have some letters to send to some MEP's!!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VoteWatch has the results of the *[Negotiations for the Transatlantic Trade and Investment Partnership (TTIP)](http://www.votewatch.eu/en/term8-negotiations-for-the-transatlantic-trade-and-investment-partnership-ttip-motion-for-resolution-vote-.html)* of 08/07/2015, but it says **436 For** and **241 Against**.

It lists how all MEP have voted and many other interesting statistics, including if the single parlamentarian were loyal to their group. It also shows that the two main groups *European People's Party* and *Progressive Alliance of Socialists and Democrats* voted for the resolution, but there were many defections by the *S&D* members.

Comment: +1 and accepted. THIS IS GREAT! Thank you! I would've preferred an official resource but this is perfectly fine.

Comment: I also usually prefer official resources, but this one seems to have been quicker and, it seems to me, that the great organization of the data make easier to understand what has happened.